# Converging sequence in the unit circle

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-numbers, solution-verification, proof-writing

Let $ (z_n)_{n \in \Bbb Z_+} $ be a sequence in the unit circle $ S^1 $ such that it converges to $z_0$. Let also $x_n$ and $x_0$ be the unique elements of $[0,2\pi[$ such that $z_n = e^{ix_n}$ and $z_0 = e^{ix_0}$. Now, I have a question concerning the following claims:

- $(z_0 \neq 1) \implies (x_n \to x_0)$
- $(z_0 = 1) \implies$ $x_n$ may be divided into two subsequences: one converging to $0$ and one converging to $2\pi$

are they true? and if so, how can one prove them?

I have tried proving them for a while now but without any success so far. My main problem is that I can not seem to prove that, for example, $|z_n - z_0| < \epsilon$ forces $|x_n - x_0| < \delta$, where $\delta$ depends on $\epsilon$ and becomes smaller as $\epsilon$ becomes smaller. I have also tried to represent everything geometrically by using angles, properties of circles etc., however I can not make the passage into a rigorous proof.

---

Any comment or answer is much appreciated and let me know if I can explain myself clearer!

Comment: Construct the sequence of complex numbers $z_1 - z_0, z_2 - z_0, z_3 - z_0.$  In complex Analysis, if the limit of the real portions is $u$ and the limit of the imaginary portions is $v$, then the complex sequence converges to $(u + iv)$.  When $z_0 \neq 1$, there will be a $\delta$-neighborhood around $z_0$ that does not *cross or contain* the point $[1 + i(0)].$  When $z_0$ equals $1$, then any $\delta$-neighborhood will (potentially) contain points on both sides of $[1 + i(0)].$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prove the first part  by looking at the limit points of $(x_n)$. Since this sequence is bounded it has limit points and it converges iff it has  a unique limit point.

Suppose $(x_{n_k})$ converges to $x$. Then $e^{ix}=e^{ix_0}$ and we have $0 \leq x \leq 2\pi, 0\leq x_0 <2\pi$. Now $x-x_0$ must be a multiple of $2\pi$ and the inequalities $0 \leq x \leq 2\pi, 0\leq x_o <2\pi$ force $x$ to be equal to $x_0$.

Second part is similar. In this case just note that if $a,b \in [0,2\pi]$ and $a-b$ is a multiple of $2\pi$ implies that $a=0, b=2\pi$ or $z=2\pi, b=0$. Thus, $0$ and $2\pi$ are the only limit points of $(x_n)$.

Comment: To show that the sequence $x_n$ has a limit point in $[0, \pi]$ we can use the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem right?

Comment: Yes, that is right. @MatteoMenghini

Comment: Why every subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}$ of $\{x_n\}$ is convergent ?